# MongoDB get count of distinct values

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

Lets say I have a collection of records:

```
{'name':'record1', 'colors':['red','green','blue']}
{'name':'record2', 'colors':['red','orange']}
{'name':'record3', 'colors':['red','yellow','blue']}
{'name':'record4', 'colors':['red','green','blue']}
```

I can get a list of distinct colors using:

```
collection.distinct('colors')
#returns
['red','green','blue','orange','yellow']
```

is it possible to get a count of the records that those values occur in?

For example:

```
[{'count':4,'color':'red'},{'count':2,'color':'green'}]
```

Comment: Use an Aggregation Pipeline with a  `group`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An aggregation pipeline using the [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) stage like this:

```
db.collectionName.aggregate( 
  { $unwind: "$colors" }, 
  { $group: { "_id": "$colors", "count": { $sum: 1 } } }, 
  { $project: { "color": "$_id", "count": 1 } }
);
```

for your documents will result into

```
{ "count" : 1, "color" : "yellow" }
{ "count" : 1, "color" : "orange" }
{ "count" : 3, "color" : "blue" }
{ "count" : 2, "color" : "green" }
{ "count" : 4, "color" : "red" }
```

Don't forget to change collection name.

Comment: The last pipeline stage could be also like `{ $project: { _id: 0, color: "$_id",  count: 1} }`

Comment: Yes, of course, it represents the same result. Simply wanted to achieve single document with an array of colors as a result, just like in the question. That's why I grouped them.

Comment: For reshaping documents, it's better to use the `$project` operator. If you replace your last pipeline stage with that projection, you would have a better result without that `_id` and `color_freq.`.

Comment: Yes, I agree, `$group` stage has another purpose than reshaping documents and with `$project` it will still give the same result, thus updated the answer.